# OpenSSH connection times out after few minutes

Tags: ssh, openssh

I usually have no difficulty in connecting to the cluster. But these days, SSH connection keeps dropping after a minute with the message `ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.x port 22: Connection timed out`. While connected, I keep pressing keyboard keys in order to make sure that the problem is not inactivity. Once the connection drops, I cannot reconnect immediately, getting the same message and need a minute to reconnect. It is as if port 22 on cluster stops listening periodically. I tested stability of internet connection with ping website and it reported no fails.

Comment: Did you ask your local system administrator if there are any known problems currently?

Comment: Have you checked the logs on both systems?